# Congratulations on **300k** Harper

Tags: discussion

#### Congratulations Harper on hitting <s>100,000</s> <s>200,000</s> 300,000 reputation!

2024-03-12 Update: Harper is now the first person to reach **300,000** imaginary internet points on DIY!

2021-11-02 Update: Harper is now the first person to reach **200,000** imaginary internet points on DIY!

Harper: You have been an inspiration to me as I have worked my way up through this site. I have learned a lot from your many answers. Sometimes I'll start reading an answer on one of the StackExchange other sites and after 2 paragraphs I'll say "I bet that's a Harper answer", and it usually is. Your answers are thoughtful and your attitude is welcoming. Keep up the good work!

(Someone will likely say "that's not a real question, delete it", but in this current mess going on across StackExchange, it is nice to see some good news.)

Comment: I love good news and couldn't agree with you more. I've learned so much from Harper (and Ed  and ThreePhase and you). You ask Harper what time it is and he tells you  the time and how to build a watch.  Too bad I've been retired for many years.

Comment: “Did you know that Harper just hit 100,000 rep?” - that’s a question! And congrats to Harper.

Comment: The greatest praise I ever gave someone was thinking I was reading Harper. Dude sure knows how to format. Being right doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Just found this graph - https://stackexchange.com/users/7546260/harper?tab=reputation . Pretty neat to see.

Comment: That's a pretty awesome accomplishment and we got to see it and benefit from it.